# Records not getting caught in if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a sample dataframe below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy_financial as npf

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'loannum': [111, 222],
    'datadt': [dt.datetime(2024, 2, 29), dt.datetime(2024, 2, 29)],
    'balloondt_i': [dt.datetime(2024, 8, 1), dt.datetime(2024, 8, 1)],
    'balloondt': [dt.datetime(2024, 8, 1), dt.datetime(2024, 8, 1)],
    'currbal': [21662536.64, 32424669.41],
    'rate': [7.349, 7.349],
    'pmtfreq': [1, 1],
    'int_only': [None, None],
    'dpd_mult': [1, 1],
    'prinbal': [0, 0],
    'prinamt': [0, 0],
    'pmtamt': [34669, 51893],
    'intamt': [0, 0],
    'intbal': [0, 0]
})
```

when I run the following code, I get unexpected negative results for the `prinbal` and `prinamt` fields. For loan 111, I get `-97995.98` and loan 222 I get `-146681.08` for both `prinbal` and `prinamt`. I expect `3038254.50` for loan 111 and `4547685.23` for loan 222.

```
for idx in df.index:
    dpd_mult = df.loc[idx, 'dpd_mult']
    datadt = df.loc[idx, 'datadt']
    balloondt_i = df.loc[idx, 'balloondt_i']
    currbal = df.loc[idx, 'currbal']
    rate = df.loc[idx, 'rate']
    pmtfreq = df.loc[idx, 'pmtfreq']
    pmtamt = df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt'] if not pd.isna(df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt']) else None
    int_only = df.loc[idx, 'int_only']
    intbal = df.loc[idx, 'intbal']

    if balloondt_i <= datadt + relativedelta(months=+1):  # Approximates 'intnx'
        df.loc[idx, 'prinamt'] = df.loc[idx, 'currbal']
    else:
        for i in range(dpd_mult):
            if currbal <= 0:  # Break if current balance is zero or negative
                break

            df.loc[idx, 'intbal'] = df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] * rate / 1200 * pmtfreq

            if int_only == 'IO':
                df.loc[idx, 'prinbal'] = 0

            elif intbal >= pmtamt:
                nperiods = max(1, 12 * (balloondt_i.year - datadt.year) + (balloondt_i.month - datadt.month) - (i - 1) * pmtfreq) / pmtfreq
                df.loc[idx, 'prinbal'] = npf.pmt(rate * pmtfreq / 1200, nperiods, currbal) - intbal

            else:
                df.loc[idx, 'prinbal'] = df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt'] - df.loc[idx, 'intbal']

            df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] -= df.loc[idx, 'prinbal']
            df.loc[idx, 'prinamt'] += df.loc[idx, 'prinbal']
            df.loc[idx, 'intamt'] += df.loc[idx, 'intbal']
```

I'm not sure why the loans are not getting caught in the `elif` statement. I can filter the dataframe for records where `df.loc[df['intbal'] > df['pmtamt']]` and I get back the expected results. `intbal` is getting calculated correctly. I've tried moving the `elif` to the first evaluation but received the same results. I tried explicitly calling the two fields using `elif df.loc[idx, 'intbal'] >= df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt']` and still get the same results.

My expected output is

| loannum | prinbal | prinamt | intamt | intbal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 3038254.50 | 3038254.50 | 132664.98 | 132664.98 |
| 222 | 4547685.23 | 4547685.23 | 198574.08 | 198574.08 |

Comment: can you share what the expected output should look like?

Comment: `currbal` doesn't change during the loop. Why not use `elif currbal > 0:` before the loop?

Comment: Run the code in a debugger or add print statements so you can verify that the variables you're testing have the values you expect.

Comment: @Barmar could you elaborate on the `elif currbal > 0:`? Before which loop? And I've printed the variables along the way and written to a csv file to see the outputs. I'm not sure why these records are not getting caught in the `elif` statement and are flowing through to the final `else` statement where `prinbal` is set to `pmtamt - intbal`.

Comment: You have `if currbal <= 0: break` in the `for i` loop. That condition doesn't change during the loop, so if it's true it will be true at the beginning and you shouldn't bother with the loop at all.

Comment: `intbal` is `0`, so `elif intbal >= pmtamt:` is never true. Are you expecting `intbal` to be updated when you do `df.loc[idx, 'intbal'] = df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] * rate / 1200 * pmtfreq`?

Comment: @Barmar, yes I am expecting `intbal` to be updated with that line. `intbal` and `intamt` are returned correctly.

Comment: Why do you expect that? When you assign a variable it just gets the value, it has no permanent link to the expression that was used to assign it. E.g. if you do `a = b + 1` and then reassign `b`, it won't change `a`.

Comment: @Barmar, I understand you now. Thank you for making that clear. I'm getting the same results as you below. I will need to dig deeper into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            elif intbal >= pmtamt:
```

uses the original value of `intbal` that was assigned earlier. If you want to get the updated value of the `intbal` cell in the dataframe row, you have to use `df.loc[idx, 'intbal']`.

```
            elif df.loc[idx, 'intbal'] >= pmtamt:
```

When I make this change it goes into the `elif` block, although the final result is still not what you expect. It's

```
   loannum       prinbal       prinamt         intamt         intbal
0      111 -3.170919e+06 -3.170919e+06  132664.984806  132664.984806
1      222 -4.746259e+06 -4.746259e+06  198574.079578  198574.079578
```

I haven't examined your calculations, I don't know what they're supposed to do or why you're still getting a different result. This just fixes the `elif` problem.